# How to recursively update dependency version in pom.xml

Tags: java, git, powershell, maven, pom.xml

I am working on developing open source plugins which is using maven. There is no parent and child hierarchy and all of the  maven projects in the current working directory are independent of each other and they are hosted on git. All of my plugins have one common dependency which I am manually updating for now.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectA</groupId>
    <artifactId>agent-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  ..............
 <dependencies>
```

Can someone please help me is there a `maven` way or `powershell` way or `git` way to update the dependency version to recursively update all of my projects in the current working directory's version to `0.13.5-SNAPSHOT` whose `groupId` is `org.projectA`

Comment: If the projects are independent in the Maven sense (no parents, no multi-module), there is no Maven way to do it.

Comment: @JFMeier Thanks for the response, I dont mind if it can be done in any other way instead of doing it manually.

Comment: When you say recursively, do you mean that there are many XML files in subdirectories that may include that xml definition you want to replace?

Comment: @AdminOfThings Yes there will be many `XML` files in the sub-directories and I need to replace the  `<version>` in all of them

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in PowerShell if your data is in xml files by reading your data from an xml file and storing it as an XML document object. You could use this with a combination of `Get-ChildItem` to find all of the xml files within a specified path.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content pom.xml)
$xml.dependencies.dependency.where({$_.groupId -eq "org.projectA"}) |
   ForEach-Object {
      $_.version="0.13.5-SNAPSHOT"
   }
$xml.Save("c:\temp\pom-updated.xml")
```

In the example above, I am reading xml data from a source file pom.xml. Then storing the updated xml object in pom-updated.xml. I believe the `Save()` method requires the full path to the output file.

For recursing through all files and overwriting the files with updated values, you can do the following:

```
foreach ($xmlFile in (Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp\test1" -recurse -include "*.xml" -File)) {
    $xml,$xmlNodes = $null
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $xmlFile.fullname)
    $xmlNodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//dependency").where({$_.groupId -eq "org.projectA"})
    if ($xmlNodes) {
        $xmlNodes | ForEach-Object { $_.version = "0.13.5-SNAPSHOT" }
        $xml.Save($xmlFile.fullname)
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to update the file directly instead of saving the file as a different file?

Comment: Save it with the same name

Comment: Can it be saved with relative path instead of absolute path?

Comment: @RanPaul, I've added another code block that will recurse through all the xml files and update those files that match your condition.